# Created RPM gives error with dependency that is already installed

Tags: rpm, fpm

I'm trying to create RPM package from source using fpm. This package unfortunately does not exist on RHEL/Centos7 so I have to build it from scratch.

What I did so far:

- Downloaded source code and run ./configure --prefix=/usr
- Created another folder and did make DESTDIR=/root/myfolder install

Now I'm building package using this command:

```
fpm -s dir -t rpm -C /root/myfolder --name libassuan --version 2.5.5
```

Now if I try to install the package it says:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        libassuan.so.0()(64bit) is needed by (installed) gpgme-1.3.2-5.el7.x86_64
        libassuan.so.0()(64bit) is needed by (installed) gnupg2-2.0.22-5.el7_5.x86_64
        libassuan.so.0(LIBASSUAN_1.0)(64bit) is needed by (installed) gpgme-1.3.2-5.el7.x86_64
        libassuan.so.0(LIBASSUAN_1.0)(64bit) is needed by (installed) gnupg2-2.0.22-5.el7_5.x86_64
```

Using --nodeps doesn't work. If I specify these 2 packages in my fpm command by adding -d (for dependency) it still complaining about dependency:

```
Error: Package: gpgme-1.3.2-5.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: libassuan.so.0(LIBASSUAN_1.0)(64bit)
           Removing: libassuan-2.1.0-3.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libassuan.so.0(LIBASSUAN_1.0)(64bit)
           Updated By: libassuan-2.5.5-1.x86_64 (/libassuan-2.5.5-1.x86_64)
               Not found
```

libassuan.so.0 is a symlink to a different file (after installation)

```
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root          root              22 May 20 13:32 libgpg-error.so -> libgpg-error.so.0.32.0
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root          root              22 May 20 13:32 libgpg-error.so.0 -> libgpg-error.so.0.32.0
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root          root          618632 May 20 13:32 libgpg-error.so.0.32.0
```

What am I doing wrong ? Did I miss something ?

Comment: What software are you trying to build? `fpm` is not the best choice, alas. Just use `rpmbuild` directly...

Comment: trying to build pinentry-1.1.1 from source that is not available for Centos7. Package libassuan along with gpg-error are its dependencies